# How to round DateTime of Joda library to the nearest X minutes?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

How to round `DateTime` of `Joda` library to the nearest `X` minutes ?
For example:

```
X = 10 minutes
Jun 27, 11:32 -> Jun 27, 11:30
Jun 27, 11:33 -> Jun 27, 11:30
Jun 27, 11:34 -> Jun 27, 11:30
Jun 27, 11:35 -> Jun 27, 11:40
Jun 27, 11:36 -> Jun 27, 11:40
Jun 27, 11:37 -> Jun 27, 11:40
```

Comment: Is your X always going to be a factor of 60?

Comment: Yes. `X` is actually a fraction of an hour.

Comment: Starting from the hour, then?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[The original accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11222664) doesn't correctly handle datetimes that have seconds or milliseconds set. For completeness, here's a version that does handle that correctly:

```
private DateTime roundDate(final DateTime dateTime, final int minutes) {
    if (minutes < 1 || 60 % minutes != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("minutes must be a factor of 60");
    }

    final DateTime hour = dateTime.hourOfDay().roundFloorCopy();
    final long millisSinceHour = new Duration(hour, dateTime).getMillis();
    final int roundedMinutes = ((int)Math.round(
        millisSinceHour / 60000.0 / minutes)) * minutes;
    return hour.plusMinutes(roundedMinutes);
}
```

Comment: #round*Copy() is proper way of rounding dates in Joda

Comment: @MaciejŁopaciński: So why don't you add an answer with such a solution?

Comment: @Qerub you misunderstood me - above answer is using round*Copy() and it is not marked as answer to this question as it should be.

Answer (score 17):

Using pure DateTime (Joda) Java Library:

```java
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1385577373517L, DateTimeZone.UTC);
// Prints 2013-11-27T18:36:13.517Z
System.out.println(dt);

// Prints 2013-11-27T18:36:00.000Z (Floor rounded to a minute)
System.out.println(dt.minuteOfDay().roundFloorCopy());

// Prints 2013-11-27T18:30:00.000Z (Rounded to custom minute Window)
int windowMinutes = 10;
System.out.println(
    dt.withMinuteOfHour((dt.getMinuteOfHour() / windowMinutes) * windowMinutes)
        .minuteOfDay().roundFloorCopy()
    );
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  All of the rounding is being done in the arguments to the withMinuteOfHour call.  the .minuteOfDay().roundFloorCopy() that follows is doing nothing.

Comment: Actually it rounds all the units smaller than 'minute', because withMinuteOfHour operates only on the minutes. This is the proper way of doing it. There is a small typo, it should be minuteOfHour() though

Answer (score 9):

I once hacked this Method to do something like it. It's not optimized in any way, but it did what I wanted at the time. Never made it in any production environment, and I cannot tell you anything about performance.

```
@Test
     public void test() {
         System.out.println(roundDate(new DateTime().withMinuteOfHour(13)));
         System.out.println(roundDate(new DateTime().withMinuteOfHour(48)));
         System.out.println(roundDate(new DateTime().withMinuteOfHour(0)));
         System.out.println(roundDate(new DateTime().withMinuteOfHour(59)));
         System.out.println(roundDate(new DateTime().withMinuteOfHour(22)));
         System.out.println(roundDate(new DateTime().withMinuteOfHour(37)));
     }

    private DateTime roundDate(final DateTime dateTime) {
        final double minuteOfHour = dateTime.getMinuteOfHour();
        final double tenth = minuteOfHour / 10;
        final long round = Math.round(tenth);
        final int i = (int) (round * 10);

        if (i == 60) {
            return dateTime.plusHours(1).withMinuteOfHour(0);
        } else {
            return dateTime.withMinuteOfHour(i);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's another approach that uses arithmetic on Unix time for completeness:

(Implemented in Scala for clarity.)

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, Duration}

def roundDateTime(t: DateTime, d: Duration) = {
  t minus (t.getMillis - (t.getMillis.toDouble / d.getMillis).round * d.getMillis)
}
```

Example usage:

```
roundDateTime(new DateTime("2013-06-27T11:32:00"), Duration.standardMinutes(10))
// => 2013-06-27T11:30:00.000+02:00

roundDateTime(new DateTime("2013-06-27T11:37:00"), Duration.standardMinutes(10))
// => 2013-06-27T11:40:00.000+02:00
```

Comment: "Implemented in Scala for clarity." ROFL

Comment: Clarity as in one less type cast, one less static method invocation and fewer parenthesis in this case. :)

Comment: This will not correctly handle leap seconds. Also, floating point should not be used here, it will lead to inaccuracies and the rounding can be more efficiently implemented with integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 6):

When you want to round [Joda DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) the best solution IMHO is to use the built-in `roundHalfCeilingCopy` and `roundHalfFloorCopy` methods:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
DateTime newDateTime = dateTime.minuteOfHour().roundHalfCeilingCopy();
```

Please note that `roundHalfCeilingCopy` will favor the ceiling if halfway. You can use `roundHalfFloorCopy` in order to favor the floor in case it's halfway.

Answer (score 1):

I have a function for LocalTime class but I think it's very easy to adopt my sample for your case:

(Kotlin lang)

```
fun LocalTime.round(roundValue: Int): LocalTime {
    val timeInMillis = this.millisOfDay
    val remainder = timeInMillis % roundValue
    return when {
        remainder < (roundValue / 2) -> LocalTime.fromMillisOfDay((timeInMillis - remainder).toLong())
        else -> LocalTime.fromMillisOfDay((timeInMillis + (roundValue - remainder)).toLong())
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
var userWakeTime = LocalTime(6, 42)
userWakeTime = userWakeTime.round(15 * 60 * 1000) // userWakeTime = 6:45
```