# Rounding time up or down with Joda

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to round a time up or down with Joda using the [roundCeilingCopy](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.Property.html#roundCeilingCopy()) or [roundFloorCopy](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.Property.html#roundFloorCopy()) methods.

Rounding down seems to work properly, but when I try to round up, it doesn't work properly.

Below is my current code with the output and the desired output.  But maybe I just don't understand how those joda methods work?

I'm fairly new to java and joda and got my original code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20250692/763125)

### Code:

```
public static long RoundTime(long time, int amount) {
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(time);
    System.out.println("Rounding time: " + dt.toString());

    DateTime up = dt.withMinuteOfHour((dt.getMinuteOfHour() / amount) * amount)
        .minuteOfDay().roundCeilingCopy();
    System.out.println("Finished Rounding Time Up (" + amount + "): "
        + up.toString());

    DateTime down = dt.withMinuteOfHour((dt.getMinuteOfHour() / amount) * amount)
        .minuteOfDay().roundFloorCopy();
    System.out.println("Finished Rounding Time Down (" + amount + "): " 
        + down.toString());

}
```

### Output: (with amount=5)

```
Rounding time: 2014-01-21T13:12:00.000-07:00
Finished Rounding Time Up (5): 2014-01-21T13:10:00.000-07:00
Finished Rounding Time Down (5): 2014-01-21T13:10:00.000-07:00
```

### Desired Output: (with amount=5)

```
Rounding time: 2014-01-21T13:12:00.000-07:00
Finished Rounding Time Up (5): 2014-01-21T13:15:00.000-07:00
Finished Rounding Time Down (5): 2014-01-21T13:10:00.000-07:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(dt.getMinuteOfHour() / amount) * amount` already rounds the minutes towards zero because it uses integer division. You'll have to modify that to get the ceiled value: `((int) Math.ceil(1. * dt.getMinuteOfHour() / amount) * amount` (note the `1. *` to force the expression to use double precision - you could alternatively cast any value to double as well).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Here is my new code for rounding up:
DateTime up = dt.withMinuteOfHour((int) Math.ceil(1. * (dt.getMinuteOfHour() / amount)) * amount).minuteOfDay().roundCeilingCopy();

But I still get the undesired output.

Comment: @Hammy Stupid mistake by me - you have to remove the parentheses around the division to actually make that a double division.